# Loop get paused/diactivated inside catch() block

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, for-loop, try-catch

I am trying to send `AT` commands to COM ports, so I can find the GSM dongle. Below is the code

```
public bool findGsmModem()
    {
        bool sendStatus = false;

        //Get all the available ports
        string[] serialPorts = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

        for (int i = 0; i < serialPorts.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(serialPorts[i]);
        }

        //Iterate through all the ports sending AT commands to find a modem
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                //port.PortName = serialPorts[i].Trim();
                port.PortName = "COM7";
                openPort();

                string res = ATCommandCaller("AT", 300,"Unable to connect to the phone"); //Connecting to the phone
                //res = ATCommandCaller("AT+CMGF=1", 300); //Setting the message Format

                sendStatus = true;

                break;
            }
            catch (System.InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                //port.PortName = null;
                port.Close();
                autoInitializer();
                //port = new SerialPort();
                continue;
                //throw ex;
            }
        }

        return sendStatus;
    }
```

Here is how I call this method inside another class

```
if (sms.findGsmModem())
{
    MessageBox.Show("Modem Found: " + sms.getPortName());
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("No modem found");
}
```

OK, now in the `findGsmModem()` method if I use `port.PortName = "COM5";` the above second code works successfully and display the message. That is because the Modem is actually in COM5 and the value is hard coded, so the statement do not reach the `catch()` block.

But, if I use `port.PortName = serialPorts[i].Trim();` or `port.PortName = serialPorts[i];` then it seems like nothing is happening instead of printing the port names (inside `findGsmModem()`). Following ports are being printed

```
COM1
COM2
COM8
COM9
COM5
COM4
COM3
```

As you can see, the `COM5`, the port where the gms modem actually exists is in the 5th element of the array, so `findGsmModem()` calls `catch()` part before it access the `COM5`.

I do believe I am not getting anything when `port.PortName = serialPorts[i].Trim()` is used because it goes to the `catch()` part and something terrible happens there.

Any idea?

Here is the `openPort()` method

```
public void openPort()
        {
            try
            {
                port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);

                if (!port.IsOpen)
                {
                    port.Open();
                }

                port.RtsEnable = true;
                port.DtrEnable = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

**EDIT**
Here is the most weirdest part. I just noticed the `catch()` block never get reached when the loop is called! I tried `ex.Message` to print the stack trace, and it didn't print anything!

Comment: can you include the definition for the method **openPort()**?

Comment: @AndreidelaCruz: Thanks for the reply. I added it to the question

Comment: Just a minor tip:  In your `openPort()` method you should replace `throw ex;` with `throw;`.  This way you don't lose information (the stacktrace).

Comment: In fact your whole `catch`-block inside `openPort()` as it is now is useless (worse than useless since it removes information) and can be safely removed (and then it is not so much point in the `try`-clause either, so this leaves just the real code).

Answer (score 2):

```
    catch (Exception ex)
```

This is the trouble with catch-em-all exception handling.  You are getting an InvalidOperationException because you change the PortName property on a opened port.  That's a bug in your code, nothing actually went wrong with the serial port.

You'll need to call the Close() method if you find out that it port is not connected to the GSM modem.

Then you **can't** call Open() again on that same SerialPort instance, it takes time for internal worker thread to shut down.  Best thing to do is to create a new instance of SerialPort instead of trying to keep using the same one repeatedly.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the reply. I noticed that if I hard cord ports like 'COM7' I can get the exception 'UnautorizedAccess'. tHE ERROR seems to happen 'COM1' and 'COM2' and maybe, few others. The issue continued :( I edited the code in the way you adviced, but I didn't get which exception I should handle because I am new to C#. I am creating a new serialport inside the method autoInitializer();. The code is edited above. Please help.

Comment: If I execute something like port 1, the only thing I get is 'The thread '<No Name>' (0x484) has exited with code 0 (0x0).'

Comment: You must always call Close and create a new one, whether there's an exception or not.  Ignore the debugger notification, you are just seeing that worker thread exiting, the one I talked about in the answer.